# POST data received by server is larger than data being sent

Tags: php, json, apache, python-2.7, python-requests

I am posting a json object to a PHP 5.6 ubuntu server running apache from a python 2.7 script using requests. If I write the json object to a file it is ~155MB, although when I POST it to the web server I've had to adjust the memory_limit multiple times to avoid receiving the PHP memory limit error. It is now over 2G and I see the memory for apache go up to 1.7G while POSTING. I do not understand how the data is so bloated. Even the extra HTTPS wrappers should not increase it that much. To make matters worse the process doesn't actually finish, I receive a BadStatusLine error from the python script after a minute or so. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you posting it? Are you sure the memory goes up that much “while POSTING” already? Certainly before any parsing of the JSON happens?

Comment: it is probably not the `data` that is bloated, but rather what you do with it causes many objects to be created, like a json_decode for example, or even steps you take after a successful decode.  Show some code so people can help you.

Comment: Are you sure it is the file's size? or you guess with free capacity remaining?

Comment: @CBroe - I've tried the MultipartEncoder from requests-toolbelt, that gave a different error regarding execution time, tried setting it to 90s but not sure if I want to go high than that. Currently im just using the requset.post() function.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg - I put a return at the top of my parse function and the memory consumption still grows to over 1.7G gradually.

Comment: python POST `r = requests.post('url',json=json_data,auth=('user','pass'), verify=False, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})`

url, user, and pass have been changes for obvious reasons. json_data is a dict

Comment: @BehradKhodayar - I watch the apache usage go up as the script runs on the other side, then it drops off after the error is received.

Comment: Do you have any debugging tool activated on your server? like xDebug?

Comment: @AngeloJanosSpaziani if you have access to the http headers, look at the incoming content-length, to see if it is in accord with the size of the payload you are trying to send.  Also, try with a smaller payload to be able to instrument this without bombing, and figure out where the blowout occurs. Gluck

Comment: @BehradKhodayar - i just installed xDebug but i dont see how i would get any data from it, the docs say it will show a stack trace, but the error i get is on the python side

Comment: @AngeloJanosSpaziani you shouldn't have installed it! I was just asking as a candidate for creating very large logs on server. It both slows down your php execution & generates very capacity-killing log files.

Comment: @BehradKhodayar - okay, i removed it then. I do not have any other active debuggers installed.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg - i dont have access to the headers, when the pythong program crashes i dont get anything from the request.